# LabelEncoder Changes Every Value in Column to 'LabelEncoder()'

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I don't understand how I goofed this up so bad. Very new to coding.

I am attempting to run one pandas column through LabelEncoder on sklearn in order to change strings into values. If I don't run it through LabelEncoder, the column prints out a list of names as it should. When i use LabelEncoder, every value is literally just changed to 'LabelEncoder'. What am I doing wrong?

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import preprocessing
import numpy as np
data = pd.read_excel('Data.xlsx', sep=',')
import pandas as pd


le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
fit = le.fit(data.loc[:,'R_Name'])
data.loc[:,'R_Name'] = fit
print(data.loc[:,'R_Name'])
```

Here are my results:

```
0       LabelEncoder()
1       LabelEncoder()
2       LabelEncoder()
3       LabelEncoder()
4       LabelEncoder()
5       LabelEncoder()
6       LabelEncoder()
7       LabelEncoder()
8       LabelEncoder()
9       LabelEncoder()
10      LabelEncoder()
11      LabelEncoder()
12      LabelEncoder()
13      LabelEncoder()
14      LabelEncoder()
15      LabelEncoder()
16      LabelEncoder()
17      LabelEncoder()
18      LabelEncoder()
19      LabelEncoder()
20      LabelEncoder()
21      LabelEncoder()
22      LabelEncoder()
23      LabelEncoder()
24      LabelEncoder()
25      LabelEncoder()
26      LabelEncoder()
27      LabelEncoder()
28      LabelEncoder()
```

Comment: Try changing `le.fit` to `le.fit_transform`? The `fit` method returns a fitted version of the `LabelEncoder` object, whereas you want to not only fit to the `'R_Name'` column, but immediately transform it and return the encoded labels.

Comment: Works perfectly! You're a champ!

Comment: Glad to hear, and have fun on your coding journey!

Answer (score -1):

I guess you want the encoded version of your column.
So you need to call the method transform on your fitted encoder.
See below

import pandas as pd
from sklearn import preprocessing
import numpy as np

```
#data = pd.read_excel('Data.xlsx', sep=',')
data = pd.DataFrame({'R_Name':['Pippo','Pluto','Paperino','Pluto','Pippo'],'ID':[1,34,5,22,1]})

le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
fitted_le = le.fit(data.loc[:,'R_Name'])
data.loc[:,'R_Name'] = fitted_le.transform(data.loc[:,'R_Name'])
print(data.loc[:,'R_Name'])
```

output is:

```
0    1
1    2
2    0
3    2
4    1
Name: R_Name, dtype: int32
```

Please note that I defined a toy dataframe because I dont't know your excel file structure. I also renamed the LabelEncoder object to fitted_le: it is not a good idea to give to a variable the same name of a method.
Actually your code could be rewritten in a more concise way (I skip the include and the dataframe import):

```
le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
data['R_Name'] = le.fit_transform(data['R_Name'])
print(data['R_Name'])
```

here is the link to the relevant documentation https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html